# How to get the index of item selected in Alert of UIAlertController Swift

Tags: swift, indexing, uialertcontroller

I am going to use UIAlertController for a user to select one item.
The items to select are array  as following:

```
let arraySelect = ["NewYork", "Washington", "Seoul", "Tokyo", "Peking", "Sidney", ... ]

   let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        // Add items in array to Alert
        for var i = 0; i < arraySelect.count; i++ {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: arrayBibleVersions[i], style: .Default, handler: {(_) in }))
        }

        // Add cancel button.    
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "취소", style: .Cancel, handler: {(_) in }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

When a user touched one item, I have to get the index of the item that a user toched on.
But I don't know how to get the index..
Please help me.

Answer (score 9):

I solved my question as following:

```
    let arraySelect = ["NewYork", "Washington", "Seoul", "Tokyo", "Peking", "Sidney", ... ]

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let closure = { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let index = alert.actions.indexOf(action)

        if index != nil {
            NSLog("Index: \(index!)")
        }
    }

    for var i = 0; i < arrayBibleVersions.count; i++ {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: arrayBibleVersions[i][1], style: .Default, handler: closure))
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {(_) in }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This unfortunately only works when you can guarantee that the strings are unique. In my scenario I am allowing people to choose family members by first name. The problem arrises when parent and child share the same first name.

Comment: As a workaround, I am going to have to add a key to the title until I can think of a better solution.  "Kevin (1234)", "Kevin (2311)", "Sandra (5122)" etc

Comment: it needs to change in swift 5 :let index = alert.actions.indexOf(action) -> let index = alert.actions.firstIndex(of: action)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it in Swift 4 / iOS11

```
projects.forEach { project in
    alertController.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(title: project.name, style: .default, handler: { action in
            if let index = alertController.actions.index(where: { $0 === action }) {
                self.showProject(project: projects[index])
            }
        })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem too and found the method below which saved me.

But be careful if the item in array are the same, it will return the first item's index.

Fortunately, It's work in this case, because we create the action and using action to search.

```
extension Array where Self.Element : Equatable {

    ...

    @inlinable public func index(of element: Element) -> Int?

    ...

}
```

It work in Swift 4

```
    let arraySelect = ["NewYork", "Washington", "Seoul", "Tokyo", "Peking", "Sidney"]

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Add items in array to Alert
    for name in arraySelect {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: name, style: .default, handler: {(action) in
            // print idx that user selected
            if let idx = alert.actions.index(of: action) {
                print("idx = \(idx)")
            }

        }))
    }

    // Add cancel button.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "취소", style: .cancel, handler: {(_) in }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working good:

```
var arraySelect = ["NewYork", "Washington", "Seoul", "Tokyo", "Peking", "Sidney"]

let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)

let closure = { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    let index = alert.actions.indexOf(action)

    if index != nil {
        NSLog("Index: \(index!)")
    }
}

for field in arraySelect {
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: field, style: .Default, handler: closure))
}

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {(_) in }))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -2):

Block is executed when the user selects a action.

```
    // Add cancel button.    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "취소", style: .Cancel, handler: {(_) in 
        //your code
    }))
```

Comment: He is asking about getting the index of selected item. He has already written the code for block.

Answer (score -2):

```
func FirefoxAhri(){
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive){
        action -> Void in
        //do stuff on click Yes
    }

    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive){
        action -> Void in
        //do stuff on click No
    }

    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        print("Cancel")
        // do nothing if you don't want. alert closes automatically
    }

    optionMenu.addAction(action1)
    optionMenu.addAction(action2)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: He is asking about getting the index of selected item. He had already implemented the code you have written :/